# Selective versioning in Document Library

Tags: document-library, versioning

I need selective versioning in Document Library in such a way that I am able to check mark versioning while uploading some specific files only (irrespective of file formats).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that on a single document library.  If you have SharePoint Server 2010, you could use the content organizer to have a single place where documents are submitted and based on your metadata (enable versioning yes/no) you could put the documents in two different libraries, one with versioning and one without.